# What Policies do Dev Teams use to Distribute ReSharper/CodeRush Licenses?

Tags: .net, resharper, coderush

I've been tasked to create a policy for our organization to determine which developers receive a license of ReSharper (this could apply to other tools like CodeRush, etc.). For example, if the organization owns 10 licenses but the team has 20 developers, how to determine *which* 10 developers get the licenses when maybe all 20 *want* them.

What policies have other people created in their organization to address this?

Based purely on seniority?  Based on skill/experience level? How do you address taking *away* licenses (if necessary)?

I know there is no code in this question but (per [SO guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)) it relates to software tools commonly used by programmers *and* matters that are unique to the programming profession.

Comment: Perhaps better to ask this on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why discriminate?  If the tools will make the programmers more productive, penny-pinching over the $300 is a gross example of a false economy.

Comment: Re. why discriminate: what if this is a pilot program to determine the tool's cost/benefit for the organization?

Comment: @Oskar, that's called a "trial version", which exists for all those products.

Comment: @Oskar Austengard - Then you wouldn't have this issue.  It would be anybody who wanted to do a trial.  And you would make a decision based on that and save some money in the process, instead of having spent half the cost of adoption on a trial run.

Comment: Voted to close - it's a management question, not programming.  It's the same question if you use the word "Pens" or "Chairs" instead of "Resharper licenses"

Comment: @Colin - OK, my mistake. Should I ask this in programmers.stackexchange.com or (based on your "pens" or "chairs" analogy) is it not OK there either?

Comment: Maybe the question should instead be:  How do you best determine the cost/benefit of a tool like ReSharper/CodeRush?

Comment: @Steve I would say it's only faintly related to programming, but perhaps if you rephrased it something along the lines of "I've been given this task because someone has made a purchasing decision without considering any use cases first - now what unique traits of programmers might I want to consider when writing this policy?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is dangerous, it's things like this that create unnecessary animosity towards your company and fellow developers.  It would probably be better to not acquire any licenses for things like resharper, than to only get enough licenses to cover half the team.  Even done "fairly" this will boil down to picking favorites when viewed by the developers.  This should be evaluated at the organizational level and addressed immediately.  I see rough waters ahead if this sort of thing were to continue.

Software developers are a unique type of people.  They will accept a lot of negative things, if they can view those things as fair.  They may say something like "My machine isn't really fast enough, but no body else has a fast machine either."  They aren't necessarily happy about it, but it's acceptable.  However, as soon as all developers that have been with the company 2 years get new fast shiny boxes, and the other developers do not there starts to be a lot of questions asked about process, and decisions, and animosity, both from the developers that were left out, and the developers who were included, because it builds tension in the team that is now directed at them through no fault of their own.  These types of things happen far too often, and sometimes we aren't at a level to stop them, but if you have any power at all over this decision, or decisions like it, take steps to improve it for the sake of your product and your deadlines.

As a final caveat.  If I had to break down who would get licenses when there was absolutely no way to cover everybody, but we still had to acquire some, would be to break it down by team.  The Website team gets resharper licenses now, and the infrastructure team will get them later. And I would make sure not to always deploy the new shiny stuff with the same teams first, mix it up a bit. In this way you could actually improve the communication amongst teams.  As there will be some interest in other teams about how Resharper is improving efficiency with the pilot team. etc.

Off the top of my head, some authors to read on topics like this are Joel Spolsky, and Tom DeMarco.

Comment: It's backwards that someone has decided the value of this tool and the number of licenses required *before* thinking about who will use it and what for.  Serious red flag for that company - I would be planning my exit strategy if I worked there.

Comment: Matthew, Colin - do you guys REALLY work for companies where everything is equal?  Are all your offices the same?  Are all your computers the same model?  Do you get paid the same?  Turn down the volume on the dramatic string sequence, please...

Comment: @Oskar equal is not the word I would use.  I can't say everything is equal, but comparable.  Also, to be clear, I'm speaking about developers, people with similar responsibilities.  I don't think it is too much to not leave anybody behind when you make a technological upgrade.  You don't have to do it all at once, but you do have to make a plan to include everyone, and make that plan clear to your staff before you begin the process.  You can get away with 10 licenses for these arbitrary developers, as long as the other 10 know they will be included, and the reasons for the wait.

Comment: I also used the words 'dangerous', and 'for the sake of your product and your deadlines' because really good developers can work anywhere, and are too important to lose.  Don't give them a reason to leave.

Comment: @Matthew - thanks for restoring the sanity.  If Steve was dealing with 20 developers who were all fungible, I would agree with your comment, but I that is likely not the case...  On a 20 person team there are likely to be several different roles and levels, from architect to junior assistant grunt - what they get out of the tool will be different depending on level.  How do you decide the cost/benefit ratio for the entire team?  Does everyone have to have the same tool set?  Or do you pay $250/head just to promote egalite?

Comment: @Oskar - We do appear to have differing scenarios in mind here when addressing this question.  To answer your last question, I think the only way you can get away with not spending $250 a head even on the 'grunts', is to have a very clear progression path from grunt to lead architect (something I have only read about, never seen in practice), and once again, a well laid out plan about what tools and accommodations are available at what levels. Equal is not the goal, fair and open are two things I am trying to get across, or you will have issues with your developers that can not easily be fixed

Comment: Bah!  This is all beside the point.  If you are paying your engineer a measly $25/hour and ReSharper saves on average 1 hour a *month* (modest, I think) then you are *still* engaging in a false economy -- *purchasing* ReSharper (or CodeRush) is *cheaper* after a year.

Comment: @Oskar It's not about equality.  I would never make a purchasing decision without thinking about the value of the thing I was purchasing, and what use I might put it to.  If you have 20 developers, look at what they are doing, look at how much the tool costs, and calculate whether the value of the tool outweighs the cost - case by case if necessary.  Once you've done that, then you're in a position to decide the number of licenses.  This a is a stupid question, it's the kind of common sense you need to shop for groceries, and being resharper doesn't make it a programming question.

Answer (score 3):

Our policy is that all devs (and testers) who want R# get a licence.

If the tool is useful why would you not give it to everyone? If cost is an issue then consider that the increase in efficiency will mean it pays for itself in a period of days or weeks (IMHO).

Comment: Steve, I'd agree with you (and your policy).  But how do you best achieve a *quantitative* measure for the gut feel both of us have, that it would pay for itself in days or weeks?

Comment: Identify some task that you perform with R#, or some issue it finds for you (e.g. unreachable code). Estimate how long that would have taken you without R#, and hence what it would have cost without R#...

Answer (score 1):

While I believe *any* developer's productivity could be enhanced by a tool like ReSharper, the primary benefit is likely around the expanded refactoring functionality. My suggestion would be to first and foremost look at the developer's role: do they need to architect/re-engineer code, or are they writing code only from scratch, according to someone else's spec?  Do they have any responsibility for the cleanliness of others' code?

On a case by case basis I would also consider whether the developer has previous exposure to ReSharper, and of course, if given ReSharper, would they take advantage of the added functionality?  (Some devs just won't, as I've experienced first hand.)